# How to import HTML content in APACHE Sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I need to import an HTML content (a field in the MS SQL Server table) to a text file using scoop. Though I didn't get any error, imported field is expected. A few HTML tags are missing. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the sqoop comment

sqoop import --driver "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" --connect \
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://abcd;instance=MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=abcd;domain=abcd.com" --username abcd -P \
 --query  "select * from abcd.html" --target-dir /user/abcd/abcd --split-by id --fields-terminated-by '|'

HTML Content Sample:

```html
EMAIL SUBJECT: FW: The Update Site URL<br />
EMAIL BODY: <div>
<p style="margin: 0;"><span style="color:#1F497D">Hello.&nbsp; I will need assistance with this so the radio 
can download calls to our server.&nbsp; Thank you.</span></p>
<p style="margin: 0;"><span style="color:#1F497D"></span></p>
<p style="margin: 0;"><span style="color:#1F497D"></span></p>
```

Comment: Please provide samples of HTML content and sqoop command

Comment: mysql html context, imported field content and sqoop command.  that's what anyone would need to solve the issue

Comment: Edited the content. Added the HTML sample and Sqoop Command